# MATLAB: How to discard overflow digits binary addition?

Tags: matlab, binary

I want to know if it's possible in MATLAB to discard overflow digits in MATLAB when I add two binary numbers.

I've only been able to find how to have a least number of binary digits, but how to I set a maximum number of digits?

For example:

```
e = dec2bin(bin2dec('1001') + bin2dec('1000'))
```

That gave me:

```
e =

10001
```

How do I get only '0001'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more robust (but less efficient, I fear) way: What you describe is exactly the modulo operation. A 4-bit binary number is the remainder after a division by `0b10000 = 16`. This can be done using the [`mod`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) function in MATLAB.

```
>> e = dec2bin(mod(bin2dec('1001') + bin2dec('1000'),16),4)

e =

0001
```

Note: I added `4` as additional argument to the `dec2bin` function, so the output will always be 4-bit wide.

This can of course be generalized to any bit width: If you want to add 8-bit numbers, you will need the remainder of the division by `0b1'0000'0000 = 256`, for example

```
>> e = dec2bin(mod(bin2dec('10011001') + bin2dec('10001000'),256),8)

e =

00100001
```

Or for shorter numbers, e.g. 2-bit wide, it is `0b100 = 4`:

```
>> e = dec2bin(mod(bin2dec('10') + bin2dec('11'),4),2)

e =

01
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Will this work for digits more than 4? Such as, what if I have 2 bytes to add instead, and the answer should only be a byte as well?

Comment: I tried it, but I changed the last 4 to an 8. I don't understand how that works though.

Comment: The important part to change is not the last 4, but it is the 16. I added two more examples to the answer. Does this help you to understand how it works, or should I add a more detailed explanation?

Comment: No, that's all. Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation! Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

`dec2bin` will always give you the minimum amount of bits to represent a number.  If you would like to retain the `n` least significant digits, you have to index into the string and grab those yourself.

Specifically, if you want to retain only the `n` least significant digits, given that you have a base-10 number stored in `num`, you would do this:

```
out = dec2bin(num);
out = out(end-n+1:end);
```

Bear in mind that this performs no error checking.  Should `n` be larger than the total number of bits in the string, you will get an out of bounds error.  I'm assuming you're smart enough to use this and know what you're doing.

So for your example:

```
e = dec2bin(bin2dec('1001') + bin2dec('1000'));
```

`n = 4`, and so:

```
>> n = 4;
>> e = e(end-n+1:end)

e =

0001
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!